# Does Intellisense support xs:key/xs:keyref?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, intellisense, vs-extensibility

Consider this XML fragment:

```
<languages default="de-DE">
  <language id="es-ES" />
  <language id="de-DE" />
</languages>
```

and an xsd that describes it:

```
<xs:simpleType name="availableCultures" id="availableCultures">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:QName">
    <xs:enumeration value="en-US"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="de-DE"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="es-ES"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
<xs:element name="languages">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="language" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="id" form="unqualified" type="mstns:availableCultures" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="default" form="unqualified" type="mstns:availableCultures" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:keyref name="defaultP" refer="mstns:languageKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@default"/>
  </xs:keyref>
  <xs:key name="languageKey">
    <xs:selector xpath="mstns:language"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:unique name="languageUnique">
    <xs:selector xpath="mstns:language"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Now, this almost works, ie. languages in the list are forced to be unique and that 'default' attribute has to refer to one of the languages in the list. I also get Intellisense support for both 'id' and 'default' fields. But I would like Intellisense to propose only languages from the list in xml file for the 'default' field - not all from the availableCultures type (after all they are the only valid ones). How do I do that?

Why do I suspect this should be doable? Because when writing the above xsd file Intellisense displayed "mstns:availableCultures" in the drop down list for 'type' attribute of 'xs:attribute' element.

What I don't know is whether this can be done using xsd alone or I would need to write some kind of VS package/add-in.

Answer (score 0):

My experience shows that this does not happen in VS 2005.